# CUDA compatibility with Tensorflow and CuDNN for Deep Learning Models

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, cudnn

I tried several combinations from this [list](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) to try and activate GPU acceleration for deep learning. However, nothing seems to work with tensorflow.

The CUDA installation works fine (by fine I mean running `nvcc --version` for example prints the correct output) and `tensorflow` is installed correctly, but I can't figure out a way to test and see what goes wrong between them.

I usually test my build like this: `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` and expect to see my graphics card listed there (or, at least, not an empty list). I have a NVIDIA RTX 3060 Ti card, so as far as compatibility with hardware goes, I don't see a probleme there.

I work with Windows 10, I know a possible alternative would be WSL2 with `conda` environments, but I want to exhaust my possibilities with Windows first.

Have any of you got any working configuration (`tensorflow`, `CUDA` and `CuDNN` versions)?

Configurations tried:
`tensorflow 2.13.0` -- `CUDA 11.8` -- `CuDNN 8.6`
`tensorflow 2.12.0` -- `CUDA 11.8` -- `CuDNN 8.6`

I also tried some variations with `CUDA 12` and the latest `CuDNN`, but neither those seem to work.

One problem I read about was that compatibility with Microsoft Store installed Python was questionable, so I reinstalled my envirnoment with an official release of Python3.11, but to no avail.

Comment: TensorFlow 2.13 does not support GPU acceleration in Windows, only in WSL. This is since TensorFlow 2.10, see the warning here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip